# Processing won't display game over screen

Tags: java, drawing, processing

I have a processing game i am designing that is supposed to display a game over screen when the game is lost. Unfortuinately, the game over screen never comes up. Here is the function i have it narrowed down to:

```
if (lives < 1) {
background(0);
textSize(100);
text("You Lost",10,10);
delay(1000);
lives = 10;
x = (int)random(width);
y = (int)random(height / 2);
velocity = new PVector(1,random(-1.4,-0.6));
score = 0;
}
```

When the amount of lives goes to zero, it pauses for a second and then restarts the game.

I have tried everything i can think of, but still no luck.

Comment: We have to see more code, for example what does the function text() or background() do?

Comment: For those who use java, text() displays text at specified coordinates. Background() clears the screen and fills in with the specified color (0 represents black). delay() pauses for a number of milliseconds.

Comment: What library are those functions from?

Comment: Wait what language is this?

Comment: Processing ( http://www.processing.org ). it's a graphical language based on java and openGL.

Comment: Oh ok sorry I didn't know about that :D thought this was java code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out:
i added a piece of code at the start of my loop:

```
if (dflag) {
  delay(2000);
  dflag = false;
}
```

and then, i put the regular update code in an else statement after it check weather you die:

```
if (lives < 1) {
  // for(int df = 0; df < 1000; df++) {
  background(0);
  textSize(100);
  text("You Lost",100,100);
  dflag = true;
  //redraw();
  lives = 10;
  x = (int)random(width);
  y = (int)random(height / 2);
  velocity = new PVector(1,random(-1.4,-0.6));
  score = 0;
} else {
  textSize(13);
  background(0);
  stroke(255);
  text(score,10,10);
  String l = "";
  for (int q = 0; q < lives; q++) { l += "%"; }
  text(l,50,10);
  strokeWeight(balld);
  point(x,y);
  strokeWeight(8);
  line(paddlex,height - 30,paddlex + paddlew,height-30);
}
```

Comment: Glad you got it figured out.

Answer (score 0):

So my best guess, having gotten to know the processing language 2 minutes ago is the following:

Because you set the background to black (0) the text can't be seen because it is black as well, maybe try changing the text's color to something else with the `fill()` method to see if that's causing the issue.

```
if (lives < 1) {
   background(0);
   textSize(100);
   fill(255, 255, 255); // White text
   text("You Lost",10,10);
   delay(1000);
   lives = 10;
   ...
```

Comment: the problem is that the screen never clears before it delays for 1 second

Comment: So the screen doesn't even go black before the delay?

Comment: you forgot a semicolon: fill(255, 255, 255); // White text

Comment: Yes, I'm guessing there is a function that takes a buffer (drawn to) and outputs it to the screen. this is probably run at the end of each Draw().

Comment: Is there no way for you to force a "redraw" of the screen at a certain point in the code?

Comment: I saw there's a function called `redraw()` maybe call that before the `delay(1000)`? Just fishing for something here :)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41917/discussion-between-octoshape-and-thedoctor)